# Cambiar el valor de una variable dentro del método subscribe()

Tags: angular, asincronismo, programacion-asincrona

Necesito comprobar de forma segura que mi usuario ha ingresado sesión para que pueda acceder a ciertas rutas que están protegidas y que pueda ver ciertos botones y enlaces que solo los debería ver un usuario ingresado, para eso hago uso de dos métodos en un servicio:

```
 //Método que se encarga de enviar las cookies con el token de autenticación a mi servidor:
  tokenVerify(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      this.API + 'token-verification',
      {},
      {
        observe: 'response',
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );
  }

  //Función que se encarga de capturar la respuesta de mi servidor despues de haber comprobado si 
  //el token es válido o no y devolver una respuesta de tipo boolean para ser usada en otras 
  //partes de mi aplicación:
  isLoggedIn(): boolean { 
      this.tokenVerify().subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("Respuesta de validacion: " + response.body.tokenValidation);
        if(response.body.tokenValidation){
          this.validation = true;  
        }
      });
      console.log("Dato de retorno del método: " + this.validation)
    return this.validation;
  }
```

la variable:

```
public validation = false;
```

Esta inicializada a false por defecto en mi servicio, pero su valor siempre se mantiene en false, al comprobar la consola me doy cuenta de que esta variable no cambia porque la respuesta del servidor se tarda mas que mi código, osea un problema de asincronia, me gustaria que mi funcion devuelva siempre un boolean y no un "Promise boolean" y en caso de que no exista manera alguna de que funcione este enfoque ¿Cómo puedo castear una variable de tipo "Promise boolean" a una de tipo boolean? o ¿eso tampoco es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo programación asíncrona por lo que ya no puedes usar returns ahora tienes que reaccionar a los cambios

analizando tu código

supongamos que en algún lugar tienes

```
if (isLoggedIn()) {
  Redirect();
}
```

ahora tu código

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean { 
      // EN ESTE PUNTO this.validation es igual a false
      this.tokenVerify().subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("Respuesta de validacion: " + response.body.tokenValidation);
        if(response.body.tokenValidation){
          this.validation = true;  // ESTA ASIGNACIÓN SUCEDE DESPUÉS DEL RETURN
        }
      });
      console.log("Dato de retorno del método: " + this.validation)
    return this.validation; // ESTE RETURN SUCEDE ANTES DE QUE SE TERMINE tokenVerify()
  }
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es ejecutar el código o la función dentro del subscribe

```
isLoggedIn(): void { 
          // EN ESTE PUNTO this.validation es igual a false
          this.tokenVerify().subscribe((response) => {
            console.log("Respuesta de validacion: " + response.body.tokenValidation);
            if(response.body.tokenValidation){
              this.validation = true;  
              Redirect(); // Este sería el código a ejecutar 
            }
          });
          console.log("Dato de retorno del método: " + this.validation)
      }
```

Una segunda opción sería hacer a tu variable `validation` un Observable y observar esta. Esto sería para tener un mejor orden del código

```
validation = new Subject<boolean>();
```

luego tendrías un subscribe para validation:

```
this.validation.subscribe(
  value => {
    if (value) {
        Redirect();
    }
  }
)
```

y en tu isLoggedIn:

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean { 
      this.tokenVerify().subscribe((response) => {
        if(response.body.tokenValidation){
          this.validation.next(true);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: LPZadkie, Y ¿si yo creo una Cookie que tenga la respuesta de validación dentro del método subscribe() y luego la saco para usarla? supongo que seria correcto encriptar la respuesta antes de meterla en una cookie para que no se vea la lógica? porque es que de otra forma no veo manera yo necesito un true o un false para proteger rutas y usar ese true o false en las directivas de mis vistas para esconder botones y enlaces.

Comment: si usualmente se hace eso, es el servidor el que se encarga de la veracidad y expiración del token por lo que puedes guardar el token en cookie y leerlo después para que no tenga que volver a ingresar usuario y contraseña, y si el usuario se desconecta pues se borra el token y si el token expira pues tendrás que manejar eso para que vaya a la interfaz de login. Demás está decir que por ningún motivo guardes el usuario y contraseña en cookie ni en ningún lado